# CakePHP 3 - How to validate multiple select field (belongsToMany Association)

Tags: validation, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

How to validate in CakePHP 3 multiple select field (belongsToMany Association)? All I need is validation rule.
Multiple select field:

```
      <!--select multiple-->
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="control-label">Group:<em>*</em></label>                          
        <select name="newsletter_groups[_ids][]" class="form-control" multiple>
          <option></option>                                 
          <option value="1" selected>Group 1</option>                                 
          <option value="2" >Group 2</option>                                 
          <option value="3" selected>Group 3</option>                                 
          <option value="4" selected>Group 4</option>
                          </select>
        <label class="error"></label>                
      </div>
```

Comment: What kind of validation rule?? Do you need a minimum number of selections? Max number of selections?

Comment: I need a minimum number of selections.

Answer (score 2):

Add in NewsletterTable.ctp

```
$validator
      ->add('groups', 'custom', [
        'rule' => function($value, $context) {
                    return (!empty($value['_ids']) && is_array($value['_ids']));
        },
        'message' => 'Please choose at least one Group'
    ]);
```